Looking for a National Geographic documentary about inventors
I am looking for a National Geographic documentary about inventors. It is a very old video probably from the 80s.
I remember it starts showing some kids and their inventions, one of connected a rake to a bike in order to sweep the leaves faster.
The documentary ends with the history of the laser.

I found it, the name is National Geographic Specials Miraculous Machines (1985).
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0477047/

If this is correct then mark it as the answer. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question.
